# written set of functions as a union of Borel measurable set

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, functions, metric-spaces, continuity

Denote by $\mathcal{H}$ the set of bounded and continuous maps $ h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $h(0)=0$.

I wonder if you can write $\mathcal{H}$ as (not trivial) $F_{\sigma}$ set in $\mathcal{H}$ ( in the topology induced by  supreme metric)?

I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: It's a straight closed set, I would say.

Comment: $\mathcal{H}$ is closed , but I want a non- trivial enumerable union.

Comment: Why? And a countable union of $F_\sigma$ is again an $F_\sigma$, BTW.

Comment: It 's true, I 'll edit my question , sorry

Comment: No need for being sorry, just trying to get the question straigh.t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $B_n = \{ f \in \mathcal{H} : \sup_{\mathbb{R}} |f| \le n\}$ be the sup-norm ball of radius $n$ centered at 0.  Note that $B_n$ is closed.  Then $\mathcal{H} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_n$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! can be approximated the $B_n$ set for compacts?

Comment: @Tirifilo: I'm not sure I understand - are you asking whether a ball $B_n$ can be written as a countable union of compact sets? It cannot. In any infinite-dimensional Banach space, compact sets are nowhere dense, so by the Baire category theorem, any countable union of compact sets will have empty interior.

Comment: what you say is true . thanks for the clarification